# Как создать изображения из массива и раскрасить как в matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pillow

Создаю изображения из массива данных, выполнив перед этим всякие математические операции.

До этого отрисовывал в matplotlib:

```py
np.save(workfolder1 + '\\merge', Mpic)
#pathcsv = workfolder1 + '\\Allmerge.txt'
#np.savetxt(pathcsv, Mpic, delimiter=',', fmt='%4.1f')
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (24, 20)
value = -1
Mpic = np.ma.masked_where(Mpic == value, Mpic)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(length=0, width=0, labelsize=0, labelcolor='w')  # Размер подписи  #  Цвет подписи
title = 'Температура поверхности моря  ' + YMD
plt.title(label=title, loc='center', fontsize=26, fontweight='bold', pad=10)

cmap = copy.copy(mpl.cm.jet)
cmap.set_bad(color='white')
cmap.set_over('gray')
cmap.set_under('#cdffff')
plt.imshow(Mpic, cmap=cmap, aspect='equal', vmin=-2.5, vmax=35, interpolation='none')

myticks = [-2.5, 0., 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10, 12.5, 15, 17.5, 20, 22.5, 25, 27.5, 32, 35]

plt.colorbar(ticks=myticks)
pathtoSphere = workfolder1 + '\\' + 'merge.png'
fig.savefig(pathtoSphere, dpi=200)
plt.close()
print('Картинка merge готова')
```

Теперь хочу сделать нормальное изображение, пробовал пилом: Создал пустое RGB изображение с размерами массива.

Как раскрасить такими же цветами как и красит MPL?

Картинка в MPL:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Исходные данные которые пытаюсь отрисовать](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18ctdTrDatYealOlLRTJ0QZdRqIt7Pb65/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: не понятен вопрос. у вас есть прямоугольная матрица, из которой вы хотите получить тепловую карту? то есть, цвет ячейки зависит от значения в ней?

Comment: @strawdog Да, матрица исходная размера ~2500 на ~2500 с глубиной 1. Матплотлиб на сколько я понял раскрашивает в псевдо цвет,  по колор мапе с моими порогами значений. А мне нужно получить все изображение в  RGB или RGBA

Comment: с глубиной в 1 как вы собираетесь получить RGB/RGBA? только оттенки серого.Либо искусстенно делать стекирование. вы можете привести пример исходных данных и желаемый результат? для воспроизводимого примера.

Comment: @strawdog исходные данные представлены в файле. А желаемый результат по цветовой палитре указан в вопросе, и сделанный в matplotlib

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает изображение от matplotlib?

Comment: @strawdog мне нужно изображение с таким же размером, отдельно без оформления и тд..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще существует встроенный метод `matplotlib` - `imsave`:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Mpic = np.load("merge.npy")
value = -1
Mpic = np.ma.masked_where(Mpic == value, Mpic)
cmap = plt.get_cmap("jet")
cmap.set_bad(color='white')
cmap.set_over('gray')
cmap.set_under('#cdffff')

plt.imsave("3333.png", Mpic, cmap=cmap, vmin=-2.5, vmax=35)
```

сохраняем в файл 3333.png

А вот и сам файл, размеры оригинала сохранены (2784х2784), здесь для отображения я уменьшил размер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]